# Ionic-firebase: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: iphone, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I wrote a simple one-to-one Chat App using Ionic and AngularFire. I used Firebase as the backend db.  I am facing an issue when deploying my app to a real iPhone device (iOS9). My app runs into the following error while fetching data from Firebase.

**Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.  https://,firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=21262351&cb=12&v=5**

My app can fetch data from Firebase via web browser (while testing with **ionic serve** ).  It can even fetch data when I first deploy to a real iphone device, but after a period of time, maybe an hour or a couple of hours, the SSL error issue start occurring...

Have anyone here ever running to the same issue before? I have been trying to remove my app and install it again on the iphone device, but same situation kept happening again and again.

I don't know if this is an iOS/iPhone issue or firebase issue? I created an firebase account but I didn't do any security configuration and leave it the default setting (no need to authenticate, because I am still in testing mode), is that matter?

I appreciate any comments and suggestion, idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same exact problem as yours, while I'm not sure about the cause of the problem exactly I assume it is related to the recent restrictions in iOS 9 regarding HTTPS

I've tried the following and it worked for me, add this code block to your app's info.plist:

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
  <dict>  
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>  
  <true/>  
  </dict>
```

My app works fine after that.

Comment: I think it is related to iOS 9.